# regular expressions, modrewrite php apache

Tags: php, regex, apache, mod-rewrite

can any one see the problem with this?

the url is this normally:

page_test.php?page=latest_news&id=10518271191304876236

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ page_test.php?page=$1&id=$2

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

latest_news is not matched by `[a-zA-Z0-9]` because of the underscore `_`: you could use the word character class `\w`, which includes the underscore:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ page_test.php?page=$1&id=$2
```

If the `id` is always **numeric**, you could shorten it even more using the number character class `\d`:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\d+)$ page_test.php?page=$1&id=$2
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no `/` in your URL, and your pattern is requiring one:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ page_test.php?page=$1&id=$2
                           ^---here
```

basically you're searching for:

```
one-or-more alpha-numerics separated by a / followed by one-or-more alphanumerics.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/([0-9]+)$ page_test.php?page=$1&id=$2
```

and you should be calling from:

```
www.yourdomain.com/latest_news/10518271191304876236
```